# Apply function to entire dataframe

Tags: function, dataframe, row

I am trying to recode all values in a dataframe using an if statement.

I have:

```
  a     b      c
  0     .05    0
-.02     0    -.06
-.01     0    -.08
  0      0     .09
```

I want:

```
  a     b     c
  0     1     0
  0     0    -1
  0     0    -1
  0     0     1
```

I have tried several things like:

```
def unit_weighted (x):
    if x >= 0.05:
        return 1
    elif x <= -0.05:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

new = df.apply(unit_weighted, axis=0)
```

I get this error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I don't want to have to list all the columns like this:

```
new = df['a'].apply(unit_weighted, axis=0)
new = df['b'].apply(unit_weighted, axis=0)
```

Any help please?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I am working with this code now and get the same error. def binaryscore(zscore):
    if zscore > 3:
        return 1
    else: 
        return 0

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `axis=0`, and it will apply element-wise.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I am getting the same error.